# Bibtex error: I didn't find a database entry for "["

Tags: bibtex

I want to submit an article to a journal and it has its own template with its own document class (available [here](https://files.taylorandfrancis.com/rqufLatex.zip?_gl=1*y573ft*_ga*Nzc0OTc0MzIxLjE2ODM3MzE4MzI.*_ga_0HYE8YG0M6*MTY4MzczMTgzMy4xLjEuMTY4MzczMTg4MS4wLjAuMA..&_ga=2.116220869.274835176.1683731833-774974321.1683731832)). I can compile the tex file into a pdf (although with error messages), but the references don't show up (they are in a separate bib file).

Consider the following working example (I use the template's bib file):

```
\documentclass{rQUF2e}

\begin{document}

\title{Whatever}

\author{Whoever}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Blablabla
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

To estimate the risk-free term structure, do this \citep{ed84}.

\bibliographystyle{rQUF}
\bibliography{rQUFguide}

\end{document}
```

The following error message appears:

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2022)
The top-level auxiliary file: proba.aux
The style file: rQUF.bst
Database file #1: references.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "["
(There was 1 warning)
Process exited normally

In the pdf, the `\citep{ed84}` command appears as [?,]]ed84.

I am unable to fix this and a topic with a similar problem didn't help.

I also tried with the journal's example tex file and bib file, but the same happens.

I tried it in Texstudio under Windows 10 and Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1.

Comment: Hi, welcome! I am afraid that without more data *and* an example of code that fails, it will be impossible to find a solution. Please try to produce a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407), or at least say *which* journal and which template is...

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the post with a working example. Thanks!

Comment: Also, "compiling with error messages" doesn't count.  If there's an error message, the pdf is a guide about what TeX thinks happened.  But you need to resolve errors messages before you can worry about what the pdf looks like.  (This doesn't apply to warnings.)

Comment: It's true, but as long as it generates the document to be submitted, I'm fine with that. In a standard article class, there is no error message and everything works fine. And to be honest, Latex error messages are always a mystery to me as I have difficulties to understand them.

Comment: @sebszab, the format is very old and doing questionable things, like overriding system packages. Fortunately, a rollback can magically make it work again, see my answer. But the editors should think about changing it (also, it uses OT1 encoding ... brrrr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you posted is not an error, it's just a warning from `bibtex`. The are numerous errors when compiling the main file, starting with:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \negmedspace already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

and ending with a worrying

```
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \ifx \@unusedoptionlist \@empty \else \@latex@warning@...
l.3 \begin{document}
```

If you look closely, the "package" you are pointing to is **overriding** system files, namely:

```
amsbsy.sty amsfonts.sty amsmath.sty amssymb.sty epsfig.sty graphicx.sty natbib.sty rotating.sty subfigure.sty
```

which is a no-no. If I remove all that files (so using the distribution's one), there are fewer errors, but the `Extra endgroup` error stays, and now there is a new one (on the second run)

```
(./proba.bbl
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@bibsetup 
                      {0}\global \c@NAT@ctr \z@ 
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{0}
```

which explains why the bibliography is not built.

**CONCLUSION:** The class is utterly broken, you have to talk to the journal's editors.

**BUT THERE IS A WORKAROUND**

If you read the source, the class has been last updated in 2014, and it has used the policy of modifying internal things. [If you add the line (thanks to David Carlisle)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63544587#63544587)

```
\RequirePackage[2018-12-01]{latexrelease}
```

*before* the `documentclass`, so that the LaTeX kernel is "backported" to the past, the compilation works, so if you compile, call `bibtex`, and compile two times more you'll have:

[image]

Still, the format is broken and seems unmaintained since 2014, which is a lot of time...

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks a lot! Now it seems to work. I never really understood the Extra endgroup type of errors, they are not clear to me at all.
The class is then definitely broken and I'll let them know. I tried to use the hyperref package as well, but it didn't work either.